Getting the Main functions code of a .NET executable using only Python
I have a c# .NET executable sample with the following structure (when opened in a disassembler, for example DnSpy) :
->executable_name
`->PE
`->Type References
`->References
`->{ } -
`->qCaVAPJGIk
    `-> OltkKtykOO
        `->Base Type and Interface
        `->OltkKtykOO(): void...
        `->GetProcAddress....
        `-> ...
        `-> ...
        `-> Main()

Is there any way I can read this .exe with python and somehow parse it and get the Main functions code?
I gave it a try with pefile and capstone modules but without luck. The only thing I managed was to extract embedded resources with the following code, but can't seem to be able to parse the functions of the program:
import pefile
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Reflection")
clr.AddReference("System")
from System.IO import StreamReader
clr.AddReference("System.IO")
from System.Reflection import Assembly

def extract_embedded_resource(assembly_path, resource_name, output_file):
    try:
        # Load the assembly from the specified path
        assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assembly_path)

        # Get all the embedded resources within the loaded assembly
        for resource in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames():
            if resource == resource_name:
                # Open the embedded resource stream
                resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)

                if resourceStream is not None:
                    try:
                        # Read the content of the resource
                        streamReader = StreamReader(resourceStream)
                        content = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                        

                        # Optionally, write the content to an output file
                        with open(output_file, "w") as f:
                            f.write(content)
                            print(f"Resource '{resource_name}' extracted to '{output_file}'")
                            return  # Exit function after extracting the resource
                    finally:
                        # Ensure the stream is closed
                        resourceStream.Close()

        # If resource is not found
        print(f"Resource '{resource_name}' not found in the assembly.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error extracting resource: {e}")

My try with the capstone did not manage to find anything related to main:
from capstone import *

def extract_main_function_code(pe_path):
    # Load the PE file
    pe = pefile.PE(pe_path)
    print(dir(pe))
    # Iterate over the PE sections
    for section in pe.sections:
        # Check if the section contains executable code
        if section.Characteristics & 0x20:
            # Extract the code from the section
            code_offset = section.VirtualAddress
            code_size = section.SizeOfRawData
            code_data = section.get_data(code_offset, code_size)

            # Initialize Capstone disassembler
            md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_32 if pe.FILE_HEADER.Machine == 0x014c else CS_MODE_64)

            # Disassemble the code
            for insn in md.disasm(code_data, code_offset):
                # Check if the disassembled instruction is the start of the 'main' function
                if 'main' in insn.op_str:
                    # Print the disassembled instruction
                    print(f"Address: 0x{insn.address:08x} \t {insn.mnemonic} {insn.op_str}")

    # Close the PE file
    pe.close()


"I gave it a try with pefile and capstone" looks like you forgot to post the code you're asking about

@MathiasR.Jessen I just edited my post. Didn't think of providing the code as it fails to parse the main functions code... But you are right, it could provide some insight as to what I am doing wrong.
